# How to pick data out of a row and display it on a form

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of dates in a spreadsheet, next to these dates are details what correspond to that date, I have a combo box which finds all the dates in the list but when I select a specific date from the drop down I want it to display the corresponding data in that row in text boxes on a form, so far I have:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Range
    staffName = TextBox8.Value

    rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Worksheets(staffName).Range("A16:A18"), 0)
    TextBox1 = Worksheets(staffName).Range("A" & rw).Offset(0, 1)
    TextBox2 = Worksheets(staffName).Range("A" & rw).Offset(0, 2)
    TextBox3 = Worksheets(staffName).Range("A" & rw).Offset(0, 3)
    TextBox4 = Worksheets(staffName).Range("A" & rw).Offset(0, 4)

End Sub
```

It doesnt error, but it doesnt work any ideas?

Comment: First of all, the function `WorksheetFunction.Match` return an integer value representing the index of the position containing the match to the value you are searching for. However, the returned value will not be an absolute row number, but an offset of the given range. In your case: the expected return values are either 1,2 or 3 and not 16,17 or 18.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, so where should i go from here

Comment: I would put a Break Point on `rw = WorkSheetFunction.Match` and once the line is executed, use the Immediate window (Ctrl + G) to print the value obtained. Or simply add this line right after it `Debug.Print rw`

Comment: That didnt work any other ideas?

Comment: are you sure this is all of your code? maybe you cleaned up your code before posting it online to make it more readable but you ended up removing key parts like Error handling, and such.

Comment: What didn't work? What happened? No details = no help, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing Match to the vba `Find` function, like so:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim cl As Range, wks As Worksheet
    staffname = TextBox8.Value

    Set wks = Sheets(staffname)
    Set cl = wks.Range("A16:A18").Find(Me.ComboBox1.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

    With Me
        .TextBox1.Value = cl.Offset(, 1)
        .TextBox2.Value = cl.Offset(, 2)
        .TextBox3.Value = cl.Offset(, 3)
        .TextBox4.Value = cl.Offset(, 4)
    End With

End Sub
```